# Loopback - Creating a get request with fields

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

Hello and thanks for taking your time to help me,

So I'm new to loopback, I'd like to create a request that retrieves all the data from a data source but only specifics fields.
I've read all the tutorials on the loopback guide, but I don't understand how to proceed.

Basically what i have is that :

```
XXXX.getUserWithXXXX = function(cb) {
      cb(null, 'Greetings... ');
    }
XXXX.remoteMethod('getUserWithXXXX', {
      description: "Get all users who own a XXXX",
      returns: {arg: 'greeting', type: 'string'},
      fields: {id: true, email: true},
      http: {path: '/getUserWithXXXX', verb: 'get'}
    });
```

So first, what I want to create a request that will retrieve all the data from my model, so I could filter it
And then I don't know how to filter in the code.

If anyone has any hints I'd gladly take them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the GET filters in "accept" attribute and also use "fields" filter to return specific fields of the documents.

```
XXXX.getUserWithXXXX = function(id, email, cb) {
    app.models.XXXX.find({where:{id:"id", email:"email"}, fields:{specific_field1:1, specific_field2:1}}, function(err, returnedUsers){
        cb(err, returnedUsers)
    })
}

XXXX.remoteMethod('getUserWithXXXX', {
    description: "Get all users who own a XXXX",
    returns: {arg: 'greeting', type: 'string'},
    accepts: [{arg: "id",type:"string"}, {arg: "email", type:"string"}],
    http: {path: '/getUserWithXXXX', verb: 'get'}
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer !
could you specify the use of : specific_field1 please

Comment: which fields do you want to be included in the result? age, address, ...?
use their names in "fields" filter. {fields:{age:1,address:1}}

Comment: Oh ok it's used this way, thanks a lot
and what is the "1" used for ? because i changed it to a two and nothing happened.
{fields:{age:2}}

Comment: 1 and 0  are equivalent to true and false, 1 for true, and 0 for false. e.g. if you wanted all the fields to be included except "age", you could change the "fields" filter to {fields:{age:0}}